# MySQL access denied to C# app but not to workbench

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to access a remote MySQL database. I am able to connect,execute queries through MySQL Workbench but cannot execute queries through C# app it connects with the database but queries are not executed as access is denied with 
Error:

1142: MySqlException (0x80004005): SELECT command denied to user 'abc'@'117.196.109.45' for table xyz

I am also linking a similar unanswered question [Remote MySql Access denied for user with C# code but can connect with DbVisualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062829/remote-mysql-access-denied-for-user-with-c-sharp-code-but-can-connect-with-dbvis)

Comment: You need to login through MySQL Workbench and grant permission to `'abc'@'117.196.109.45'` to be able to have `SELECT` permissions.  If you will be accessing the database from multiple locations, `'abc'@*` will allow that user from any IP address.

Comment: The workbench and C# app are run on the same PC accessing remote MySQL database with same username,password and public IP

Comment: You may have login permissions, but not `SELECT` permissions.  Try running the same query in workbench.

Comment: Yes, it does run. I am able to create,update,select,delete everything through workbench. I am really surprised as to why it's not working in C# Btw I am running the same app flawlessly within the LAN

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of security and permissions. Your MySQL Workbench is using the abc@127.0.0.1 where the ip is the localhost. But the c# app is using a remote ip the credentials that you give it in the connectionstring.

Either change the credentials in the connectionstring if you are on the localhost, in the web.config (or app.config if its not a webapp).

Or change through the Workbench the permissions and allow that server 117.196.109.45 permission.

See this video for setting permissions with the Workbench:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSdbNoW2f-c

See this video for general troubleshooting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY

Comment: Thanks, actually it was a connection string mistake that was causing the problem.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh what was the connection string problem? It seems i'm having a similar problem

Comment: @philr I am extremely sorry, this issue happened a long time back, don't remember what caused it except that it was a mistake I made in the connection string.